# How to debug while testing in sailsjs

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, mocha.js, sails.js

I am trying to debug a 500 Internal server error in sailsjs. I have written tests in mocha and am getting the error from there. I am not sure on how to run a debugger when I start the testing with npm run test.

I am getting the error from another file, is it possible to put breakpoints over there and view it while testing

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is the solution that I came up with.

```
Using VScode,

configure the launch.json to be

{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Mocha All",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
      "args": [
        "--timeout",
        "999999",
        "--colors",
        "${workspaceFolder}/test/**/*.spec.js"
      ],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    },
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Mocha Current File",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
      "args": ["--timeout", "999999", "--colors", "${file}"],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    }
  ]
}
```

Change according to how the test files are labeled in your project